# Enable spring boot tests based on VM options

Tags: spring, junit, spring-test

I want to run some test classes and disable running some other test classes based on VM options.
What are the possible ways to achieve this?

VM option will be like : `-DENABLE_FEATURE1_TEST=false -DENABLE_FEATURE2_TEST=true`.

I have tried using Junit 5 property
`@EnabledIfEnvironmentVariable(named = "ENABLE_FEATURE1_TEST", matches = "true")`
 on the test class, but using this still runs the tests in the class.

Similarly, i have also tried using `@Conditional` annotation, with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-DENABLE_FEATURE1_TEST=false` sets a JVM system property named `ENABLE_FEATURE1_TEST`, not an operating system environment variable.

So, you would need to use:

```
@EnabledIfSystemProperty(named = "ENABLE_FEATURE1_TEST", matches = "true")
```